# How should I structure optional fields/models within Django Model?

Tags: django, django-models

I need to collect "notes" from my Django App users, and there are two types of notes with differing fields / field types.  The flow would be like this:

1. Create new note.
2. Select the note type.
3. Fields are contextual to the note type model definitions
4. View all notes.

Should I create a separate model for each note type with the appropriate fields and then somehow combine them in the views?  **Is there a better way to structure this so that it is more extensible?**

Comment: You could create an abstract `Note` model with numerous children (one for each note type). Then could create an ajax view whose job it is to return the actual form HTML itself, depending on what type of note you want.